# Mvvmcross Making multiple markers on Google Maps

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am very new to Xamarin and MvvmCross. I am trying to create a sample app but I am stuck. What I am trying to do is that access my observable collection from ViewModel into my view. I am filling the list in my ViewModel with Geocodes that I get from as an API response and I want to access those geocodes into my view so that I can make markers on my Google map. Is there a way to do this.

### Edit:

Here I am adding the response into my observable collection.

**FirstViewModel.cs**

```
var item = response["Response"]["SearchResults"]["Location"];

if (item.Type == JTokenType.Array)
{
    JArray lst= (JArray)list;
    Length = lst.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
    {
        ResultLists.Add(new ResultList
        {
            Latitude = (string)response["Response"]["SearchResults"]["Location"][i]["Geocode"]["Latitude"],
            Longitude = (string)response["Response"]["SearchResults"]["Location"][i]["Geocode"]["Longitude"]
        });
    }
}
```

And in my view, I want to be able to get those Geocodes that I saved in my collection to make markers on the map.

**FirstFragment.cs**

```
public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
{
    _map = googleMap;

    //I am trying to access that list of Geocodes here to make markers on my map

    //LatLng marker = new LatLng(ViewModel.Lat, ViewModel.Lng);
    //Console.WriteLine("Google Map Marker Location: " + marker);
    //googleMap.MoveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.NewLatLngZoom(VimyRidge, 13));          
    //googleMap.AddMarker(new MarkerOptions().SetTitle("This is VimyRidge!").SetPosition(VimyRidge));
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet of code pertaining to this?

Comment: @samusarin I have edited my question. Please take a look. Thanks!!

Comment: Have you successfully setup your ViewModel bindings for other Model data (besides the map info), or is that  what your trying to figure out with this issue?

Comment: @samusarin Yes, I have successfully setup my ViewModel bindings for other Model data.

Comment: Are you working with Xamarin.Forms, or straight MvvmCross?

Comment: Straight MvvmCross

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150746/discussion-between-nick-king-and-samusarin).